# How to build a Libra TestNet with two servers？

Tags: diem

I want to build a Libra TestNet with two servers.

I don't know how to use config-builder to configure the program.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit late but it might help for someone who is looking for a solution.

I was able to setup local test network with single/multiple nodes based on the following

1. For a single node, the `libra-swarm` package is well documented here https://developers.libra.org/docs/run-local-network and defines easy steps to setup your local test network with defined number of nodes.
2. If you are planning to use multiple nodes, you can use docker files and shell scripts to create docker images from [Libra's github repo](https://github.com/libra/libra/tree/master/docker) and use those images with some container-orchestration system like kubernetes to setup your network. I was able to do this and have it setup using in this [github repository](https://github.com/pariweshsubedi/libra-kubernetes-document-verification/tree/master/kube/libra).